# 'Delete geometry' node not working as expected

Tags: mesh, geometry-nodes, procedural

I am trying to create a procedural terrain generator in blender. I have created three array modifiers and applied geometry nodes to the produced points.[image: my node tree so far]

When I set the threshold to 0.5 all of the points exist, but anything below that and they all disappear. Is this a problem with my usage of the noise function? I want to delete some random points, but it appears to just be all or none. Do you know why this is happening?

UPDATE: I used the node tree in the answer to do this in 2 dimensions, and then upon changing back to my original one it suddenly worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without the file you are using it is hard to say exactly what is wrong. When I recreate the same setup with a [Grid-node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.5/modeling/geometry_nodes/mesh/primitives/grid.html) instead of using the *Geometry* input I get the result I think you are looking for:
[image: Using Noise to remove a portion of vertices from a grid]

Probable reasons why your case isn't working are then:

- The noise is always less than your threshold
- The type of geometry you are applying this to isn't a mesh
- The modifier isn't visible in the viewport

To troubleshoot these you can use a [viewer node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.5/modeling/geometry_nodes/output/viewer.html) together with the [Spreadsheet editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.5/editors/spreadsheet.html#index-0).

Comment: Is there any way I could make this in 3d? I need a 3d array.

Comment: [Instance](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.5/modeling/geometry_nodes/instances/instance_on_points.html) [mesh lines](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.5/modeling/geometry_nodes/mesh/primitives/mesh_line.html) on the grid and [realize them](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.5/modeling/geometry_nodes/instances/realize_instances.html), then convert that to points like above.

Comment: See the update I added above.